# NLog не загружает Rules из XML конфигурации

Tags: c#, логирование, nlog

Содержание конфигурационного файла, собственно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
  </extensions>

  <targets async="True">
    <target name="TraceLogger"
            type="File"
            fileName="${TraceFullPath}"
            archiveFileName="${TraceArchiveFullPath}"
            maxArchiveFiles="100"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            archiveEvery="None"
            layout="${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*"
            minLevel="Trace"
            writeTo="TraceLogger"
            enabled="True" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Тестовый код:

```
var configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(configurationPath);
var factory = new LogFactory(configuration);
var logger = factory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Trace("Message");
```

VS показывает следующие значения для объектов:

```
configuration.base.LogginRules: Count = 0
configuration.base.AllTargets: Count = 0
logger.Is...Enabled = false (for all levels)
```

И, стоит ли говорить, что сообщение не логгируется.
Есть какие-нибудь идеи по поводу того, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

А вся проблема заключалась в декларировании переменной `TraceLogname`, но использовании переменной `TraceLogName` для сборки пути `TraceFullPath`.

Answer (score 0):

инициация логера

```
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); //log
```

использование

```
   logger.Debug("mes");
```

nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >


  <!-- optional, add some variabeles
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <!-- 
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>

    <!-- 
    add your targets here 
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets for possible targets.
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers for the possible layout renderers.
    -->
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}|${level}|${message}" />
    <target name="file"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/Log.${level}.current.txt"
        layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${level}: ${message} ${exception:format=Message,StackTrace} ${stacktrace}"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/log.error.${shortdate}.{#}.txt"
        archiveAboveSize="5242880"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        archiveNumbering = "Rolling"
        maxArchiveFiles="3" />
    <!--
    Writing events to the a file with the date in the filename. 
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    -->
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
    <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
    -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

и вообще гуглится на ура http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2014/03/c.html

Comment: Так а в чем ошибка в моем конфиге?

Comment: то что вы логер не установили?  var configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(configurationPath);
var factory = new LogFactory(configuration);
var logger = factory.GetCurrentClassLogger(); - это что?

Comment: `var logger = factory.GetCurrentClassLogger();` ну как бы вот он логгер. `LogManager` берет дефолтное расположение конфига. меня это чуть-чуть не устраивает, я его перенес в `configurationPath`

Comment: используйте дефолт